# Java script Count duplicates in list of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, dictionary

I need help in consolidating a list of dictionaries by counting duplicates and placing them in an array.

**Example Input**

```
var arr = [{name: "Bob", group: "Group2"},

{name: "Peter", group: "Admin"},

{name: "John", group: "Group1"},

{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},

{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},

{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},

{name: "Tom", group: "Admin"},

{name: "Tom", group: "Group2"}]
```

**Expected Output**

## Name, # of Group1, # of Group2, # of Admins # of superuser

```
["Bob",0,1,0,0]

["Peter",0,0,1,0]

["John",1,0,0,0]

["Tom",3,1,1,0]
```

Comment: Is this array ordered already by the object names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a standard `reduce` operation, using an object to find the frequency of elements with the same name.

```js
var arr = [{name: "Bob", group: "Group2"},
{name: "Peter", group: "Admin"},
{name: "John", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Admin"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group2"}];
const idxMap = {Group1: 1, Group2: 2, Admin: 3, Superuser: 4};
const res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, {name, group})=>{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || [name,0,0,0,0];
    acc[name][idxMap[group]]++;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: for those who find counting tiresome: `const idxMap = Object.fromEntries("Group1,Group2,Admin,Superuser".split(",").map((g, i) => [g, i+1]));`

Answer (score 0):

You can group the numbers per username in a `Map` and then put the data in an array:

```js
var arr = [
{name: "Bob", group: "Group2"},
{name: "Peter", group: "Admin"},
{name: "John", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group1"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Admin"},
{name: "Tom", group: "Group2"}
];
let map = {};
let groupCategory = {
     'Group1':0, 'Group2':1, 'Admin':2, 'SuperUser':3
};
arr.forEach(user => {
     let group = groupCategory[user.group];
     if(!map[user.name])
          map[user.name] = [0,0,0,0];
     map[user.name][group]++;
});
arr = Object.entries(map).map(e => {
     return [e[0], ...e[1]];
});
console.log(arr);
```